# Spark MiniCluster

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to create a "Spark MiniCluster" entirely programmatically to run small Spark apps from inside a Scala program? I do NOT want to start the Spark shell, but instead get a "MiniCluster" entirely fabricated in the Main of my program.

Comment: So, not Spark standalone cluster?

Comment: No - I won't do anything on the command line at all. Just compile my Scala program and run it, in IDEA. As if I didn't even have a shell.

Comment: IDEA compiles your app and runs a shell process in the background, though

Comment: If you are asking how to configure your Scala to run as a Spark application only by clicking the Run button, then that is done by editing the Run Configurations

Comment: no no - I want to programmatically start Spark.

Comment: I don't really know what that means, nor think that is how you are supposed to [run Spark applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create application and use local master to start Spark in standalone mode:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object LocalApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "local-app", new SparkConf())
    // Do whatever you need
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

You can do exactly the same thing with any supported language.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can do similar things in python also with equivalent API calls - there is no need to instantiate a shell session from within scala, java or python.